# Pass Filter Parameter To DBContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, dbcontext

Inside an ASP.Net Core Web app, what is the correct way to pass a value to the DB Context class to use it as a filter?

I need to filter the data returned across all pages of my ASP.Net Core web app. The filter will be based on the logged in user. If the logged in user is from Branch 6108 then they should only see that branch's data. If I use the raw value I can filter by saying

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>().HasQueryFilter(b => b.BranchID == 6108);
```

The problem is we have 50+ branches so the number will be different for any logged in user.

So ideally I want it to say

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>().HasQueryFilter(b => b.BranchID == branchFilter);
```

Where branchFilter is a value I discover and pass after getting the logged in user by using

```cs
@User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: make `branchFilter` a property/field of your `DbContext`. see the [Global Query Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters#example) example with _tenantId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initiate your DbContext you could inject the required user data, store it in a field and then use this in your query.  For this you can create an interface for this user data and then inject the implementation of the user data through dependency injection.  After that you can use the field in your `HasQueryFilter`.

For example:

```c
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    private string branchId;
    private string userId;


    public YourDbContext(DbContextOptions<YourDbContext> options, IGetUserProvider userData) : base(options)
    {          
        tenantId = userData.BranchId;
        userId = userData.UserId;
    }
// ...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>().HasQueryFilter(b => b.BranchID == branchId);
    }
}
```

And an example on how to get the user from the HttpContext, where your user holds a claim to the branch.  You should of course have an implementation of `IGetUserProvider` that is relevant to your use case.

```
public interface IGetUserProvider
{
    string UserId { get; }
    string BranchId { get; }
}

public class GetUserProvider : IGetUserProvider
{
    public string UserId { get; }
    public string BranchId { get; }

    public GetTenantClaimsProvider(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        UserId = accessor.HttpContext?.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == UserIdentifierClaimName)?.Value;
        BranchId = accessor.HttpContext?.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == BranchIdentifierClaimName)?.Value;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could create a public property or method on your implementation of `DbContext`, but you would need to remember to always set the data before querying any dataset.  That's a highly likely mistake with considerable consequence that can be avoided by injecting the required data.

For a full guide on this topic, please read Jon P. Smith's proposed design: https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/part-4-building-a-robust-and-secure-data-authorization-with-ef-core/

Comment: Really grateful for the help however, it has led to an additional issue which I have added to the original post and I would be grateful if you can offer any insight.

Comment: I am not familiar with the pattern where you new up the DbContext, and I wonder if that's a different pattern from elsewhere in your code (I would expect you inject your DbContext where needed).  It looks to me that the `config` is missing when you new up the `TimeSheetContext`, but it's difficult to understand with the limited code.

Comment: Thanks @Superman.Lopez , the issue in the edit was unrelated to your solution. Your suggestion did fix it.