# How to Pass global filter value to DB Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, dbcontext

I have been asking specific questions but don't seem to be getting the issue resolved. I can not imagine that my situation is unique so I am going to ask in as bare bones a way as I can and hopefully someone will see my issue.

I have a DB Context for a razor pages app. I will need to apply a global filter to certain entities, however, this filter will be different depending on the user but will never change during session.

In essence what I need is

```cs
public TimeSheetContext(DbContextOptions<TimeSheetContext> options, int Branch)
            : base(options)
        {            
          
            branchFilter = Branch;
            
        }
```

Once branchFilter is set I will apply the filter as

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>().HasQueryFilter(b => b.ContractorCode == branchFilter);
```

Logically it seems like such a simple issue but whenever I add anything to the CTOR such as int Branch above, the code will not run. Specifically it says that my connection string from appsettings doesn't exist whereas it clearly does as if int Branch is not their and I set the raw value of branchFilter = 6108; (as an example) it works fine.

So my question boils down to how do I pass any value into the context constructor.

You can see the following 2 questions for where I have been asking in much greater detail.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69573453/pass-filter-parameter-to-dbcontext)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69591037/invalidoperationexception-when-using-context-injection-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Apparently your problem is with DI. There is no way to make DI inject `int` into the constructor, but the approach from Question 2 should work as soon as you  do not have other public constructor. Which apparently *do* have (and DI is using it instead of the one you have shown), otherwise you won't get that error.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev, that has helped solve it. If you add it as an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by removing the blank constructor I had in the context.
All credit for the answer goes to Ivan in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
public TimeSheetContext(string connectionString) : base(GetOptions(connectionString))
{
}

private static DbContextOptions GetOptions(string connectionString)
{
    return SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), connectionString).Options;
}
```